# is it possbile to dowload one part of a file from web?

Tags: linux, unix

lets say there is one very big file on some server and i just want to download first 1MB. How can I do it on Linux ?

Comment: Originally asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518968/is-it-possbile-to-dowload-one-part-of-a-file-from-web

Answer (score 4):

If the server supports it, `curl -o filename -r 0-1048575 http://url/to/file` will just download the first MB.

Comment: i like this better than my answer :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
wget URL
```

then Ctrl + c when about 1MB has been written.

If you want exactly 1MB, then you can run the downloaded chunk through `split`

```
split --bytes=1048576 FILENAME
```

you can even pipe `wget` into `split` so that the file gets saved as 1MB chunks as it downloads... see the man pages.